# VS linker can't find PsGetProcessWow64Process

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker, wdk

I am trying to compile one driver in VS, but it shows -

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__PsGetProcessWow64Process@4 referenced in function _GetProcessModule@8 Garhal  C:\Users\Raitis\source\repos\GarHal_CSGO\Garhal\memory.obj  1
```

Quickly enough, I found a place, where this `PsGetProcessWow64Process` is being used https://prnt.sc/uffavf

But it is defined, and it's even an official ntos.h function. Just pressing F12 on it finds it easily - https://prnt.sc/uffbjg

Screenshot from error list - https://prnt.sc/uffc6t

Comment: You should have turned for github support rather than posting this on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this in undocumented functions and the linker is having a hard time finding where is the function to put a pointer to it in the generated binary, so first include `ntifs.h` before `ntddk.h` like this

```
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
```

it must be before ntddk or you will get weird errors

then add this line :

`NTKERNELAPI PVOID PsGetProcessWow64Process(__in PEPROCESS Process);`

which is the signature of the function and now you are ready to call that function

---

another way to get it is using function pointers and resolving it at run time

```
#include <ntddk.h>

typedef struct _PEB32 { 
    UCHAR InheritedAddressSpace; 
    UCHAR ReadImageFileExecOptions; 
    UCHAR BeingDebugged; 
    UCHAR Spare; 
    ULONG Mutant; 
    ULONG ImageBaseAddress; 
    ULONG/*PPEB_LDR_DATA32*/ Ldr; 
} PEB32, *PPEB32; 

typedef PPEB32 (NTAPI * pfn_PsGetProcessWow64Process) (PEPROCESS Process);
pfn_PsGetProcessWow64Process PsGetProcessWow64Process = NULL; 
RtlInitUnicodeString (&usFunctionName, L"PsGetProcessWow64Process"); 
PsGetProcessWow64Process = (pfn_PsGetProcessWow64Process) (SIZE_T)MmGetSystemRoutineAddress (&usFunctionName); 
pPEB32 = PsGetProcessWow64Process (pEProcess);
```